# Access chart changing text number to scientific notation

Tags: ms-access, report

I have a bar chart object on an access report. Labels display my 8 digit text number properly. When I add a data table to my classic Access charts, my labels change to scientific notation.

I have verified all fields from tables, queries, forms, reports, etc. are text. I have tried reformatting the data and fields. Nothing seems to work.

Has anyone ever come across this and how do you fix it? This data is input directly into the database and is not imported from a spreadsheet.

Table1 - Un_ID is Auto Number and Un is Short Text.

| Un_ID | Un |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345678 |
| 2 | 12345679 |
| 3 | 12345680 |

Table2 - G_ID is Auto Number, G_num/Un_ID/Base/Actual are Integers, G_name is Short Text.

| G_ID | G_num | G_name | Un_ID | Base | Actual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | G1 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | G2 | 1 | 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 1 | G1 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | G2 | 2 | 2 | 12 |

Query1

```
SELECT Table1.Un, Table2.G_num, Table2.G_name, Table2.Base, Table2.Actual FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Un_ID = Table2.Un_ID WHERE (((Table2.G_name)="G1"));
```

Chart Query

```
SELECT Query1.[Un], Sum(Query1.[Actual]) AS SumOfActual
FROM Query1 GROUP BY Query1.[Un];
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'add a data table'? Are you using classic MSGraph or ModernChart? I have Access 2010 and can use only MSGraph. Do you mean the Data labels or Axis labels? Yes, I have seen scientific notation. Edit question to show sample data as a text table.

Comment: The data table displaying value beneath a chart. I attached a photo. It’s all I can do as a sample for various reasons. Notice the label is in scientific notation. It is supposed to be a 7 digit numerical string.

Comment: Okay, I've never bothered with displaying data table. I increased width of chart and reduced font size from default of 16 to 8 and that removed SN. Edit question to show sample of your data as text table and the chart RowSource if you want me to test further.

Comment: Or at least a table structure and some sort of data that could represent your situation. There is no reason this cannot be done.

Comment: Sorry about that. I wasn't in a position to give sample data. Here is the sample tables, queries, and chart.

Comment: I did not save my earlier test and cannot replicate what I thought was success. For your data, when I reduce to 4 digits, SN goes away. Thought I found something when I formatted the chart data table x-axis column as Number with 0 decimals. The SN went away but as soon as I switched to form view it came back. Sorry, I don't see any solution.